# how do i tell nginx to handle the file after fastcgi rewrites it?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I have a asp.net app and i am using nginx with fastcgi&mono. When i visit `static.mysite.com/type/258/nicename.png` i need nginx to grab the file from `apppath/public/uploads/00/00/01/02` which is hex of 258. ATM i have asp.net rewriting the file however i am positive asp.net is still handling the file instead of nginx. I'm sure nginx would be faster and since i have the static subdomain i can skip asp.net if i have a way to tell nginx how to map the url to file

How do i get nginx to handle the file transfers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [XSendFile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile).

Comment: That looks like what i want but... how do i do that? I looked at the php example and it just sets the X-Accel-Redirect header then does nothing else. That would make it use nginx? if i set the header and i guess call response.end()? hmm. i'll try it when the server is setup but is there a good way to check if nginx is in fact serving files instead of asp.net?

Comment: yes, just a header, that page describes it. to check? :) if you don't output the file from asp.net then obviously nginx is serving it.